# Convergence of $\sum \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}z^n$ at $|z|=1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series

I know that the power series $\sum \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}z^n$ converges for $|z| \lt 1$ but I have been trying to determine what happens on $|z|=1$
Clearly the series converges at $z=1$ and diverges at $z=-1$.
I thought that a good approach would be to write $z^n = \cos n\theta + i\sin n\theta$ and use Dirichlet's test for the two real series $\sum \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} \cos n\theta, \space \sum \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} \sin n\theta$ but I can't really use it here because $\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$ is not monotonic.
Can someone give a hint with the right direction?

Comment: That's perhaps Leibniz series, I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $z=e^{it}$, then the series becomes

$$-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^ne^{int}}{n}$$

Let $a_n=(-1)^ne^{int}$, then for $t\neq\pi$:
$$\left|\sum_{n=1}^Na_n\right|=\left|\frac{-e^{it}(1-(-1)^Ne^{iNt})}{1+e^{it}}\right|\leq\left|\frac{2}{1+e^{it}}\right|$$

Then apply Dirichlet test to $a_n$ and $b_n=\frac{1}{n}$, we conclude that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nb_n$ converges, for $z=e^{it}, t\neq\pi$.

If $t=\pi$, then it becomes the harmonic series, which diverges.

Answer (score -1):

**Hint:**

For $\lvert z\rvert = 1$, consider the series representation of 
$$
\log(z) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}(z-1)^n.
$$ 
What happens for $z$ on the unit circle?

Comment: This is misleading at best: $$\frac1{1-z}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^k$$ for $|z|<1$. The series diverges for all $|z|=1$ even though the analytic function it represents is well-behaved except at $z=1$. On the other hand, once we know that the OP's series converges, the power series (together with Abel's theorem) can help us determine the actual sum.

Comment: @mrf I don't see how it is misleading. Consider $z = -1$. Then $z-1 = -1\Rightarrow z=0$; that is, $$\log(0) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}(-1)^n$$ which obviously diverges. We can determine the actual sum here as well. Consider $z=1$. Then $z-1=1\rightarrow z=2$ so $$\log(2) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}1^n$$ and so on for other values.

Comment: To "plug in values on the circle", you need to know that the series actually converges for these value. This is what the OP is asking. (Once you have established convergence, you need Abel's theorem to justify that the value you get when plugging in those numbers is what you would expect).